# angular4 interceptor causes duplicated http requests

Tags: angular, interceptor

Here is my interceptor

```
// src/app/auth/token.interceptor.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtService } from '@app/services/jwt.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public jwtService: JwtService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headersConfig = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    };

    if (this.jwtService.getToken()) {
      headersConfig['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.jwtService.getToken()}`;
    }

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: headersConfig
    });
    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

    }, (err: any) => {

    });
  }
}
```

and my app.module, everything like in documentation

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidebarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes
      , { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }
    ),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MyInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    JwtService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This causes duplicated http requests[image]

I found that when I remove setHeaders option, the problem is fixed, but I created intercepter to add authorization header in the first place. Please help me to understand what's wrong

Comment: what's weird, it's call first http (the call initialized by zonejs), waits until it's done and then call the second one

Comment: these are not duplicate requests, the first is a preflight options request validating that you are authorized to make requests on this domain, it's happening because you're adding auth headers, this is standard browser behavior.

Comment: @bryan60 so, it is the correct behavior that I see 2 http requests, when add any header? in my example I don't have auth header, cause there is no jwt token

Comment: yea pretty much any header alteration will trigger a pre flight request, it causes no performance issues whatsoever, and happens in every browser. Most of the time the request is actually browser cached.

Comment: @bryan60 thank you, so I thing I do nothing wrong. But I'm working not the first year, and never seen this behavior before. I would say it's not so usual behavior, since before I start using interceptor there was no these OPTIONS requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an authenticated request initially there is one request of the type OPTIONS that is done during the called preflight. It’s a kind of handshake with the server figuring out if it accepts requests of that type. If all goes OK it will then do the actual GET, POST, etc. request you initially did. I believe that’s what you’re experiencing.

**Edit**

Your problem might reside in the way you are setting the headers.

Try the following

```
request = request.clone({
      headers: headersConfig
    });
```

Comment: so, it is the correct behavior that I see 2 http requests, when add any header? in my example I don't have auth header, cause there is no jwt token

Comment: My edit was based on this source. Have a look and see if you can spot something you’re doing differently https://juristr.com/blog/2017/08/intercept-http-requests-in-angular/

Comment: yea, I checked this one and many other links before asking. I'm more interested in you original answer, can u give me some link about this behavior? You said it's ok, but for me it looks like 2 requests need more time then without interceptor, before that I was using custom apiService instead of interceptor for the same goal, and there was no this problem. So, I kind of doubt that this duplicated request is fine

Comment: Can you check the type of request? I’m suspecting one of them is of the type HEAD and the other of the type GET or POST or whatever was the original type.

Comment: one of them with type 'OPTIONS'

Comment: In that case it’s in line with my first explanation. It’s browser default behaviour for the preflight when you set headers. It’s testing the waters to ensure you’re allowed to make that request :). They’re not duplicate. They’re two different requests for the same flow.

Comment: thanks, I think that's it. The only question left - why it's working like this only when I use interceptor, I have other projects where I simulate interceptor behavior with custom ApiService and set headers as well - and no these OPTIONS requests. If you have and idea I would be grateful, but anyway accepting your answer, thx

Comment: To be honest I would expect that behaviour whenever you set the headers. But it’s definitely something worth digging a bit deeper :)